# How to increase heap memory size for Spock Framework?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, heap-memory, spock, bitset

The Java program runs fine but the test fails with the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.BitSet.initWords(BitSet.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.BitSet.<init>(BitSet.java:162)
    at lv.id.jc.ipv4.IntSet.<init>(IntSet.java:6)
    at lv.id.jc.ipv4.IntSetTest.$spock_initializeFields(IntSetTest.groovy:11)
```

I already set `GROOVY_OPTS` to `-Xmx1g` but it doesn't help.

I use test framework Spock 2.0 and java code under test is

```java
public class IntSet {
    private final BitSet[] storage = {new BitSet(Integer.MAX_VALUE), new BitSet(Integer.MAX_VALUE)};

    public void add(int i) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            storage[0].set(i);
        } else {
            storage[1].set(-++i);
        }
    }

    public long size() {
        return (long) storage[0].cardinality() + storage[1].cardinality();
    }
}
```

I can't find in Spock Framework documentation how to solve such a problem. I use IntelliJ and gradle.

I will be grateful for any ideas.

Addition information. I set property in gradlew file:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xmx2048m" "-Xms128m"'
```

I run the program using this command:

```bash
./gradlew run -q --console=plain --args="ip_addresses"
```

It works fine and prints the correct result. However, when I run the test with command:

```bash
./gradlew test
```

then I got an error message:

```
> Task :test FAILED 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

and the HTML report says:

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException: Multiple Failures (2 failures)  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Spock has nothing to do with the memory limit, it all depends on the JVM that executes the code. How do you run your tests (Maven/Gradle/something else)?

Comment: I use gradle and IntelliJ. I run tests from InteliiJ and from command prompt with gradlew test. You give me an idea to check settings for gradle. Thanks!

Comment: You are creating two bit sets of size 2,147,483,647 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) bits, e.g. ~256 MB each. Probably that is your problem, rather than anything related to Spock. Do they really have to be that big? In your test run configuration for IDEA, you can specify any VM parameters you wish to, so there you also have the chance to increase the heap size.

Comment: The task is calculate unique IPv4 addresses among 8,000,000,000 addresses in the text file in format ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd. So I convert them in int representation and I create a container. The second mine implementation (more performant) uses long[] storage = new long[1<<27] array and it also crashed during the tests…

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate unique IPv4 addresses"? Calculate random addresses for testing purposes? And if they need to be unique, why use an array and not a set? Of course you can calculate unique ones without randomising them by just incrementing by 1 each time, then you do not need a set.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that 8 billion IPv4 addresses need 32 billion bytes of storage space (in memory!), i.e.  ~32 GB RAM? Does your machine have that much plus the RAM for all the other applications the OS is running? Then you can use `java -Xmx40g` or so. But if you only have 32 GB or less RAM, this will fully load your CPU and HDD I/O, freezing the machine, making the computer unusable for a very long time. So you better find a smarter way to test whatever you are trying to test.

Comment: There are e.g. sorting  algorithms which can merge and sort data from ultiple files, back from the times in which computers had little memory and stored data on tapes. But before answering your question (which is completely unrelated to Spock), I would need to understand your use case. You only explained **how** you think you want to do something, but did not explain **what** exactly you want to achieve. This is called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898).

Comment: The task description: Given a simple text file with IPv4 addresses. One line - one address, like this:
```
145.67.23.4
8.34.5.23
89.54.3.124
89.54.3.124
3.45.71.5
...
```
Your task is to count the number of unique addresses in this file, spending as little memory and time as possible. You can download a sample file [here](https://ecwid-vgv-storage.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ip_addresses.zip). The file is zipped, and you should unzip it before processing. Please note that the size of the unzipped file is about 120Gb.

Comment: My program works fine processing 120Gb file and counting unique numbers in 9min. But I can't pass quality gate because tests fails.

Comment: Well, and how are you representing the data in your main program? How are you determining uniqueness there, if the data do not fit into memory? What stops you from doing it similarly in your test?

Comment: The line `new Container()` works fine in main() method and crashes in the tests. You can check the code:

https://github.com/rabestro/codereview-task1-ip-addresses/tree/dev

Comment: Correcting my statement above: There are of course ~4 billion IPv4 addresses, not 8. That was a typo. But the ~32 GB RAM needed to store them was correct. Their uniqueness can however be represented, like you did, in 4 GB of RAM, if you just use one bit per address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding configuration in build.gradle file:

```
test {
    minHeapSize = "800m"
    maxHeapSize = "2000m"
    ...
```

Comment: I added the _gradle_ tag to your question, because this was purely a Gradle problem. FWIW, I took a look at your two container implementations and find both of them quite smart. Nice idea to represent an IPv4 address by its index in the bit set and using a second bit set for the negative integers.

Comment: The next challenge would be to implement the functionality with limited memory resources, assuming that not the whole IPv4 address space can be represented in memory. Imagine IPv6.  Then you would have to sort using multiple files first and then read the sorted files sequentially, ignoring duplicate IPs (or removing them while sorting already, then calculating files sizes in order to derive the number of unique IPs.

Comment: Hm, a random access file, which you treat as a bit set, might be a way to do this, assuming you have enough disk space and can wait for long enough, considering disk I/O. Think [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). That might be a nice programming kata. Then your Java process would run with minimal RAM.